# Identificar elementos de un color en PDF mediante script en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Buen día a todos.

Tengo un script en Python que estoy usando para llevar el registro de ciertos eventos de una mesa de ayuda a partir de la información de un PDF y hasta el momento funciona de la forma esperada, salvo por un detalle: existen ciertos eventos que ejecuta un usuario y que en la mesa de ayuda se identifican con dos colores diferentes, siendo una especie de naranja para aquellos que cuentan con interacción de terceros y amarillo para los que no tienen interacción con terceros, tal como se aprecia en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego entonces, lo que estoy buscando es una forma de que el script únicamente registre aquellos que están dentro de un recuadro naranja, pero no he tenido éxito.

Para resolver lo anterior, he tratado de implementar código que identifique el color de fondo usando pdfminer, pero no he tenido éxito, ya que el resultado siempre es 0:

```
    import os
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTRect

def rgb_to_float(r, g, b):
    return r / 255, g / 255, b / 255

def count_colored_boxes(pdf_path, target_color):
    count = 0

    for page_layout in extract_pages(pdf_path):
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTRect) and element.non_stroking_color == target_color:
                count += 1

    return count

# Ruta de la carpeta 'pruebas'
folder_path = 'pruebas'

# Color objetivo en formato RGB (R255, G219 y B174 en este caso)
target_color = rgb_to_float(255, 219, 174)

# Obtener todos los archivos PDF en la carpeta 'pruebas'
pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.pdf')]

# Contar la cantidad de recuadros con el color objetivo en cada archivo PDF
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    input_pdf = os.path.join(folder_path, pdf_file)
    colored_box_count = count_colored_boxes(input_pdf, target_color)
    print(f"Recuadros con color R255, G219 y B174 en {pdf_file}: {colored_box_count}")
```

Este código únicamente busca encontrar los recuadros con el color objetivo en el PDF; la idea era hacerlo funcionar y luego incluirlo en el script principal, pero como mencioné anteriormente, no logro dar con la solución, por lo que acudo al foro en busca de ayuda para ello o bien, en caso de que alguien pueda pensar en algo mejor, soy todo oídos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso a la BD de la Mesa de Ayuda? Sería fácil haciendo las consultas pertinentes.

Comment: Hola @aeportugal; lamentablemente no tengo acceso a la base de datos, por ello me metí en este lío jeje. Gracias